# Typeorm error with unique:true in entity instance

Tags: node.js, entity, typeorm

this is my error:
QueryFailedError: ER_BLOB_KEY_WITHOUT_LENGTH: BLOB/TEXT column 'username' used in key specification without a key length

if I remove unique:true anything goes fine!

import   {
      Entity,
      PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
      CreateDateColumn,
      Column,`enter code here`
      BeforeInsert,
    } from 'typeorm';

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { response } from 'express';
//utilizzo Entity da typeorm e creo la tabella User Entity('User)
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created: Date;

  @Column({
    type: 'text',
    unique: true,
  })
  username: string;

  @Column('text')
  password: string;

  @BeforeInsert()
  async hashPassword() {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  }
  toResponseObject(showToken:boolean = true) {
    const { id, created, username,token } = this;

    const responseObject =  { id, created, username,token };
    if(showToken){
      responseObject.token = token
    }
    return responseObject;
  }

  async comparePassword(attempt: string) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(attempt, this.password);
  }

  private get token() {
    const { id, username } = this;
    return jwt.sign({
      id,
      username,
    },process.env.SECRET,{expiresIn:"7d"})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, you cannot use unique in combination with a text column.
For me, the solution was to switch the type to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

you can but the Unique beside the Entity I think it will be work

```
@Entity('users')
@Unique(['email'])
```